# Discontinuous Fourier transforms?

Tags: fourier-analysis

What's an example (or even better a large class of examples) of an $L^2$ function whose Fourier transform is discontinuous?

Comment: Try $x \mapsto \mathbb{sinc}(x)$.

Comment: The answers and comments are sinc-ronizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the inverse Fourier transform of your favourite discontinuous $L^2$ function.

Comment: for example, this is not hard to compute for a characteristic function

Answer (score 2):

Robert Israel gives the most general answer, but here is an explicit example.

By scaling [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27463/fourier-transform-of-sinc4t/142818#142818), it is shown that the Fourier Transform of the $\mathrm{sinc}$ function
$$
\mathrm{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}
$$
is the square bump function
$$
\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(1+2x)+\mathrm{sgn}(1-2x)}{2}
$$